# Increment the number part of a String but keeping the character part in Java

Tags: java, regex

I came across several questions but without an answer for my problem.

I have a code camming from data-base in this format: FR000009.

The output should be: FR000010

```
String original = "FR000009";
    String incremented = "FR" +  String.format("%0" + (original.length() - 2) + "d",
            Integer.parseInt(original.substring(2)) + 1);
    System.out.println(incremented);
```

Here came the difference from other questions: I want to parse the string without the need of hardcoding FR like in the example above. In time there can be different country codes (DE, UK,RO etc).

Comment: `original = original.replace(original.replaceAll("\\D", ""), String.format("%06d", Integer.valueOf(original.replaceAll("\\D", "")) + 1));`. Also takes care of those cases where the the original string is also postfixed with alpha characters, for example: `"FR000009DR"` or if 000009 (or similar) is the only numerical value in ***any*** string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code by stripping all digits first and then stripping all non-digits:

```
String original = "FR000009";

String repl = String.format("%s%0" + (original.length() - 2) + "d",
    original.replaceFirst("\\d+", ""),
   (Integer.valueOf(original.replaceFirst("\\D+", "")) + 1));
//=> "FR000010"
```

Here:

- `replaceFirst("\\d+", "")`: removes all digits from input, giving us `FR`
- `replaceFirst("\\D+", "")`: removes all non-digits from input, giving us `000009`

---

Note that if there are always only 2 letters at the start and remaining are digits then you won't even need a regex code, just use `substring`:

```
String repl = String.format("%s%0" + (original.length() - 2) + "d",
   original.substring(0, 2),
   (Integer.valueOf(original.substring(2)) + 1));
```

Comment: What dose this: "%s%0"?

Comment: replaceFirst() it replace only temporarily?

Comment: `%s` is for printing `string` part which is `FR` and remaining `%07d` is same as in your question to print number with padded zeroes.

Comment: `replaceFirst` replaces first instance of matched substring

Answer (score 2):

You need a method where you can pass in the country code and create a new string from the old one.

Your requirement isn't clear.  I can't tell if you always want to increment the value, regardless of country code.

I think you need a better abstraction than a String.  I don't know what this String is, but I'd recommend a class with a static counter and a method that takes in a country code and returns a String value after incrementing the counter.  No parsing needed.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just split between digits and leters:

```
String input = "FR100109";
String[] splited = input.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");
int incremented = Integer.parseInt(splited[1]) + 1;
String formated = String.format("%0"+ splited[1].length() + "d", incremented);
System.out.println(splited[0] + formated);
```